# git rebase impossible to continue with clean copy

Tags: git

I am trying to get data from my upstream branch and rebase it inside my repository.

```
user@user-X75A:~/www/my-project-erp/my-folder$ git rebase upstream/master

CONFLIT (contenu) : Conflit de fusion dans package.json
```

Got a conflict in package.json, I edit the file and add it

```
user@user-X75A:~/www/my-project-erp/my-folder$ git add package.json
```

I continue my rebase

```
user@user-X75A:~/www/my-project-erp/my-folder$ git rebase --continue
Application de  update version
Aucun changement - avez-vous oublié d'utiliser 'git add' ?
S'il n'y a plus rien à indexer, il se peut qu'autre chose ait déjà
introduit les mêmes changements ; vous pourriez avoir envie de sauter ce patch.

Lorsque vous aurez résolu ce problème, lancez "git rebase --continue".
Si vous préférez sauter ce patch, lancez "git rebase --skip" à la place.
Pour extraire la branche d'origine et stopper le rebasage, lancez "git rebase --abort".
```

Here

> strange sentence, I have a message No change, did you forgot to use
>   'git add' ?

I check status just in case

```
user@user-X75A:~/www/my-project-erp/my-folder$ git status
rebasage en cours ; sur 6e3f853
Vous êtes en train de rebaser la branche 'master' sur '6e3f853'.
  (tous les conflits sont réglés : lancez "git rebase --continue")

rien à valider, la copie de travail est propre
```

> Working copy is said clean, no conflicts remaining.

Now I start going crazy and make a double check...

```
user@user-X75A:~/www/my-project-erp/my-folder$ git rebase --continue
Application de  update version
Aucun changement - avez-vous oublié d'utiliser 'git add' ?
S'il n'y a plus rien à indexer, il se peut qu'autre chose ait déjà
introduit les mêmes changements ; vous pourriez avoir envie de sauter ce patch.

Lorsque vous aurez résolu ce problème, lancez "git rebase --continue".
Si vous préférez sauter ce patch, lancez "git rebase --skip" à la place.
Pour extraire la branche d'origine et stopper le rebasage, lancez "git rebase --abort".

user@user-X75A:~/www/my-project-erp/my-folder$ git status
rebasage en cours ; sur 6e3f853
Vous êtes en train de rebaser la branche 'master' sur '6e3f853'.
  (tous les conflits sont réglés : lancez "git rebase --continue")

rien à valider, la copie de travail est propre
```

So clearly my rebase has no conflicts but I can't continue further. What did I missed? Of course I tried to abord and retry it several times as well, but same conclusion.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You resolved the conflict by choosing the HEAD version.

You just have to `git rebase --skip` to continue.

Comment: I tried it, and it triggered again my conflict. Then i did git checkout --ours . and git add . , but was back to where I came above without going further after a new git rebase --continue

Comment: If it trigger the same conflict again and again, and you always want the HEAD version, you can skip it until the end.

Comment: Ok i tried to skip it again, and this time it solved it. Sad thing, when I tried to pull afterward I had again my conflict which I solved for the 10th time! but finally after it all was merged properly and rebased successfully. Thanks!

Comment: Avec plaisir ;)